# Apple Sign In Web implementation. Not getting User Info

Tags: oauth, apple-sign-in

We are implementing the Sign In with Apple functionality for web application. We are following the ReST based approach. The authorization call is working fine and we are getting the 'code' and 'state' values on the return request object. But I am not getting the customer info.

Authorization end point : https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize

The user info section is completely missing on the apple doc. Is anyone know which endpoint to hit for getting the user info and what is the request format.

I have tried the token API call from Apple and I'm getting the response as 'unsupported_grant_type'

Endpoint : appleid.apple.com/auth/token

Header : `svc.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Body :

```
{'client_id' : client_id, 'client_secret_key' : client_secret_key,
'grant_type' : grant_type, 'code' : code, 'redirect_uri' : redirect_uri}
```

grand_type value we set as 'authorization_code'.

Response service=AppleSignInTokenService status=ERROR errorCode=400 errorMessage={"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have tried the token API call from Apple and I'm getting the response as 'unsupported_grant_type'

Endpoint : https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token
Header : svc.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
Body : {'client_id' : client_id, 'client_secret_key' : client_secret_key, 'grant_type' : grant_type, 'code' : code, 'redirect_uri' : redirect_uri}

grand_type value we set as  'authorization_code'.

Response
 service=AppleSignInTokenService status=ERROR errorCode=400 errorMessage={"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Edit your question and put in the real code. Are you really sending: 'grant_type' : grant_type (What is the 'grant_type? )

Comment: grand_type value we set as 'authorization_code' which is mentioned in the apple doc.

Comment: @ShekharBA, i have a Wkwebview based app , going to implement apple sign in with "login with facebook". As a web view based app, i should not do any native implementation in the app. But should create service, register web URL etc to developer website ? Question 1 - Should i need to enable apple sign in for both app identifier and xcode ? 2 - Can i create multiple service ID for same primary app (one for dev site, one for live site) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you getting 400 error, check the redirect URL exist at Service ID redirect section or not. Make sure the client id is the same as the Service ID Identifier or not.

If you getting 200, but no user information returns. That could be you already do sign in with apple with your site, you could go to `https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage`, then click APPS & WEBSITES USING APPLE ID under security. If you see your site then click stop using Apple ID. Now, when you back to the site to do sign in again, the user information will be included. Seems like apple only returns user information on first time.